# What are the pros and cons of context-oriented programming (COP)?

Tags: programming-languages, dynamic-programming

I have started reading about COP, but can't really get a grip of it. What I understand is that you use layers to let the software dynmically adapt depending on the context, and this would result in less code duplication.

But other than that, what are the advantages of COP (what can I do with COP that would be hard to do otherwise)? And what are the disadvantages?

Comment: Are there working systems in practical everyday use? If not that would be a con.